# Making a link slide and open a new div to it's right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I need some help/guidance on how to accomplish this, what I am trying to do is make a div slide out to the right from the left side once an individual link is clicked. But so far, I'm struggling with it, so my question would be how to do this?

This is what I have so far.

CSS:

```
.main-header {
  width: 1020px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #555;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-top: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 22px 14px -14px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 22px 14px -14px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: 0 22px 14px -14px #000, inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
  position: fixed;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
  top: 0;
}
.main-header h1 { width: 1020px; float: left; text-align: center; }
.toggle-menu {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 6px 0 0 12px;
  margin: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000, 1px 1px 2px rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.page-wrap { float: left; -moz-transition: all .3s ease; -webkit-transition: all .3s ease; -o-transition: all .3s ease; transition: all .3s ease; }
.main-nav-check { display: none; }
.main-nav {
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.main-nav .default_logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  background: url(../images/Profiles/default_logo1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
  float: left;
}
.main-nav a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 0 0 0 169px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  color: #15ADFF;
  font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000, 1px 1px 2px rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9);
}
.main-nav a:hover, .main-nav a:focus { background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2); border-right: 7px solid #15ADFF; color: #111; }
#main-nav-check:checked + #main-nav { width: 350px; }
.close-menu { display: none; }
#main-nav-check:checked ~ .page-wrap .open-menu { display: none; }
#main-nav-check:checked ~ .page-wrap .close-menu { display: block; }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="main-nav-check" id="main-nav-check" />
            <nav class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
                <div class="default_logo"></div>
            <a href="#">Profile Settings</a>
            <a href="#">Recent Updates</a>
                        <a href="#logoff">Sign Out</a>
            </nav>
            <div class="page-wrap">
                <header class="main-header">
                <label for="main-nav-check">
                        <div class="toggle-menu" title="Options">☰</div>
                    </label>
            </header>
            </div>
```

I'm trying to make it where if I click on a link on the left side, let's say 'Profile Settings', a new div opens and slides out to the right. I would need this for each individual link displaying content in the right div once a link has been clicked from the left side, but I am struggling with it.  If anyone could provide a jsfiddle, I'd greatly appreciate it and/or respond back with additional code to make this work, again I'd be very thankful.

Here's a jsfiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/xP9wy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this changes
**http://jsfiddle.net/xP9wy/4/**

**HTML**

```
   <nav class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
         <div class="leftside"> 
                        <div class="default_logo"></div>
                        <a href="#profile" class="head">Profile Settings</a>
                        <a href="#updates" class="head">Recent Updates</a>
                        <a href="#logoff">Sign Out</a>
         </div>

            <div class="rightside">
                <div id="profile" class="section"> profile </div>
                <div id="updates" class="section"> updates</div>                   
            </div>
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-nav-check:checked + #main-nav { width: 750px; }

.leftside{
 float:left;
 width: 350px;   

}

.rightside{
   margin-top:5px;
   float:right;
   width:350px;
}

.rightside .section{

    border:#ccc 1px solid;
    display:none;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.head').click( function(){
       var a = $(this) ;
       var section = $( a.attr('href') );
       section.removeClass('section');
       $('.section').hide();
       section.addClass('section');

        if(! section.is(':visible') ){
              section.fadeIn(500);
        };
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much - I've been trying to come up with this exact solution for days!

Comment: Thank you soo much again Michael B.  That is perfect!  I honestly can't thank you enough for helping me on this!

Answer (score 0):

My example's not perfect, mainly the css, but I think this is along the lines of what you are looking for.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qqwWB/1/)

The main idea is to use jQuery's `.append()` method to append a new element to the DOM, then use standard jQuery selectors and methods (in a chain) to reposition things as desired.

```
$('.page-wrap').append('<div id="proset"></div>');
```

and

```
$('#proset')
    .hide()
    .css({
        'background-color':'yellow',
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':'150',
        'padding':'20px 10px',
    })
    .html('Click in Me')
    .slideDown(1500);
```

Note that since the new element is injected, you must use the `.on()` event handler to trap click events etc.

Here are some links for adding some additional jQuery sparkle to the animations:

[sliding elements](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)

[various animations](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/understanding-jquery-animate-function/)